# No-IP hosted server isn't reachable if I'm connected to mobile hotspot

Tags: portforwarding, noip

I'm hosting a server on my laptop, to make it reachable from the outside I'm using No-IP.
When I'm connected to my home Wi-Fi I can easly reach it from other computers because I've opened my router port, but when I'm connected to my mobile hotspot I cannot reach the server from other devices, that's because the ports aren't open. How do I open mobile hotspot's port to make the server reachable?